# Out of memory - Dispose image

Tags: c#, bitmap, out-of-memory, emgucv, dispose

I always get the `out of memory`problem. I really don't know how many `images` that I have to call `dispose`method. Whether I forgot `dispose` some `images` in my code. Each image is from 13 - 16Mb. Anyone can help me?

```
imgBox.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY);
imgBox.Refresh();
using (Bitmap bm1 = new Bitmap(imgBox.Image)) //Out of memory
{
    using (Image<Gray, byte> EmguImage1 = new Image<Gray, byte>(bm1))
    {
        Global.xrayPic.Dispose();
        Global.xrayPic = EmguImage1.Clone();
        Global.rootPic.Dispose();
        Global.rootPic = EmguImage1.Clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: How large are the images? Are you compiling for x64?

Comment: @MineR The images is from 13-16Mb and I'm compiling for any CPU

Comment: When you assign an image like that, it needs a 13-16MB contiguous block of memory - probably a LOT more if the 13-16 is in a compressed format. When on x86, you can run out of contiguous memory blocks of that size real quick. Change it to x64 (or turn off "Prefer 32 bit") in your project settings.